# Slick Slider Next Arrows not showing

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I'm trying to get the next and previous arrows to show up next to the product slider, just like in the Slick Slider example.  But my sample doesn't seem to load the appropriate fonts to make that happen.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
  <div class="slider">
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.onguardapparel.com/images/products/thumb/8013LN_Cat.jpg" height="100" width="100">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.onguardapparel.com/images/products/thumb/HiddenTailor.9074B.jpg" height="100" width="100">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.onguardapparel.com/images/products/thumb/1600ETY.JPG" height="100" width="100">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.onguardapparel.com/images/products/thumb/VIPERPRO81.jpg" height="100" width="100">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.onguardapparel.com/images/products/thumb/garment_bag.jpg" height="100" width="100">
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.onguardapparel.com/images/products/thumb/1077.jpg" height="100" width="100">
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
  body{
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  .slider{
    margin: 60px auto;
    width: 500px;
  }
  div{
    height: 100%;
  }
  p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
  }
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.slider').slick({
            centerMode: true,
            centerPadding: '60px',
            dots: false,
            infinite: true,
            speed: 300,
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            arrows: true
        });
      });
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/schwany23/j39j568c/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In your fiddle, you had forgotten to add the slick-theme.css file as an external resource. If you wanted to follow the default styling of the author, you need that file. Or if you want your own styling then please go ahead and make your own styling and make it youw own theme .css file or something.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
```

and this css for visibility,

```
.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before{
    color:red;
}
```

[The updted jsFiddle can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/j39j568c/5/).

Code snippet here...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slider').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '60px',
    dots: true,
    /* Just changed this to get the bottom dots navigation */
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 4,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true
  });
});
```

```css
body {
        background-color: #fff;
      }
      .slider {
        margin: 60px auto;
        width: 500px;
      }
      div {
        height: 100%;
      }
      p {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: white;
      }
      /* added the following to give the background color of the arrows as red for visibility, the default which can be found in the slick-theme.css was white */
      .slick-prev:before,
      .slick-next:before {
        color: red;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js"></script>
<link href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="slider">
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.onguardapparel.com/images/products/thumb/8013LN_Cat.jpg" height="100" width="100" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.onguardapparel.com/images/products/thumb/HiddenTailor.9074B.jpg" height="100" width="100" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.onguardapparel.com/images/products/thumb/1600ETY.JPG" height="100" width="100" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.onguardapparel.com/images/products/thumb/VIPERPRO81.jpg" height="100" width="100" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.onguardapparel.com/images/products/thumb/garment_bag.jpg" height="100" width="100" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://www.onguardapparel.com/images/products/thumb/1077.jpg" height="100" width="100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @SchwanPark - Glad to be of help. Now if this is an acceptable solution to your problem please do mark it (the green check mark) so that in future is someone has the same issue this may come in handy

Comment: I was including slick-theme.css, but the default arrow color is white, which on a white background is effectively invisible. @Sai's css to colour them red makes it obvious they're there.

Comment: In your HTML, you should never include a page directly from github. Search for a CDN. For example: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/slick-carousel

Comment: .slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before{
    color:red;
} this works me...thakyou

Comment: Why not `.slick-arrow:before { color: red; }`?

Answer (score 10):

if the arrow are on a white background just add a color for them in your css like this:

```
.slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before {
  color: #09529b !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have included slick-theme.css and are still having problems it is because the theme expects to be in a subfolder (e.g. /theme/slick-theme.css) but the default download puts the slick-theme.css in the same folder as ajax-loader.gif and the fonts folder which are both referenced from the theme.

Solution:
Put the slick-theme.css file in a subfolder or edit the css so that it no longer tries to look in a parent folder. You may also need to change the colour of the arrows as suggested by [Sai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3392959/sai)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to find yourself in a case of a particular logic when you don't have enough slides.

For example: if you have 4 Slides, Infinite on true and slidesToShow: 4 you will never see the navigation arrows.

Just add one more slide for make appears the navigation.

Answer (score 0):

in `slick-theme.css` the arrows are signed `-25px` so please note to change it
since you have given `margin=0px` for whole page.

Answer (score -1):

the default font size is set to 0 so you just have o set the font-size to 13px and should be appeare on hover

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).