# Slick slider arrows not showing on mobile

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I have a Testimonials section that displays slick arrows on desktop but not mobile. I thought it would be a simple CSS solution but that did not work. I'm not sure what I'm missing. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

There is another slider on the same page above this one, and slick arrows are working as expected on mobile.

HTML:

```
<section class="testimonial_section">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <h2 class="h2-center">Testimonials</h2>
        <span></span>
    </div>
        <div class="body">
    <div class="testimonial-content" data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 1, "slidesToScroll": 1, "arrows": true, "accessibility": true}'>
      <?php 
      if( have_rows('section_content') ){
          while ( have_rows('section_content') ){
              the_row();
              if(have_rows('testimonials')){
                  while(have_rows('testimonials')){
                      the_row();
                      $slider_quote = get_sub_field('slider_quote');
                      $slider_author = get_sub_field('slider_author');
                      $slider_blurb = get_sub_field('slider_blurb');
      ?>
              <div id="testimonial_inner-<?php echo get_row_index(); ?>" class="testimonial_inner_wrapper">
                  <div class="quote">
                      
                      <p>{!! $slider_quote !!}</p>
                      
                  </div>
                  <div class="author_blurb">
                          <p class="author">{!! $slider_author !!}</p>
                          <p class="blurb">{!! $slider_blurb !!}</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
          
      <?php
                  }

              }

          }
      }

      ?>  
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

JS:

```
$('.testimonial-content').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 500,
        arrows: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
              arrows: true,
            },
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              infinite: true,
              dots: true,
              arrows: true,
            },
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 480,
            settings: {
              dots: false,
            },
          },
          // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
          // settings: "unslick"
          // instead of a settings object
        ],
      });
```

CSS:

```
.testimonial_section {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: url(../images/quote.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 100px;
    @media screen and (max-width: 1200px){
                .slick-arrow {
                    display: block !important;
                }
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
    }
    .quote p {
      font-size: 2rem;
      line-height: 2.8125rem;
      padding: 2rem;
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    .author {
      color: $primary;
    }
    .slick-list {
      padding-bottom: 2rem;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28999095/) help in resolving your issue? If not, would it be possible to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), either here on StackOverflow, or on an external site (jsfiddle, codepen, some other)?

Comment: @FiddlingAway thanks for your response. That link did not help. For some reason, the slick-arrow buttons are not being called for some responsive screens. [Here's the fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/darrylfr/vnt209aL/)

Comment: Seems to be a pure CSS issue - the `button.slick-arrow` is actually inside the rendered HTML, and your JS setup is correct. See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/pvsn7m92/1/) (your fiddle with some extra CSS and some extra sliders). Check the last CSS ruleset (for `button.slick-arrow`). Made it ugly on purpose, so it stands out. :D Also, if your original background colour is white (or some shade of it), that's another thing contributing to the poor visibility. **EDIT** A better choice would be to target `.slick-previous` and `.slick-next` with separate values for `left` / `right`.

Comment: Thanks again. Your CSS addition works but my problem on the live site is the responsive/mobile view. The button code disappears in the rendered HTML at smaller screens for Portfolio and Testimonials sections (near bottom). [See live site to test responsive screens](https://www.foodpak.com/)

Comment: Looking at the live site's code while switching back and forth from the desktop to mobile, I can see that something is removing the arrows from the DOM, and I'm guessing the slick slider is being reinitialized on `resize` event. If that is indeed the case, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67143145/) *might* help in resolving the issue. If it doesn't, I've unminified your main.js, and found [this](https://i.imgur.com/m8Y9XqK.png) in the source. Change the `!1` to `!0` (or `true`), and it should work.

Comment: Well, your second idea definitely helped! I was scratching my head because I had already changed the arrows in the responsive breakpoint to "true" in the "main.js" file. However, what I needed to change was the "main_b4da861d.js" file.